# ASP.NET Output Cache Provider for AWS Redis Cache

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, caching, redis, amazon-elasticache

I am new in cloud programming so i am wondering if it is possible to use the OutputCache Directive to cache an asp.net page for AWS Redis Cache ?

I found good documentation on caching ASP.NET session state provider [HERE](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/elasticache-as-an-asp-net-session-store/) and it worked, but unfortunately i didn't find anything helpful on OutputCache.

Any guide from experts is highly appreciated.

Comment: Use CacheManager, much more flexible than just redis. http://cachemanager.michaco.net

Answer (score 0):

Here is a redis cache provider. Its targeted at Azure Redis but it should be compatible.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-aspnet-output-cache-provider

The important part is a nuget package: **Microsoft.Web.RedisOutputCacheProvider**